# How to delete all Git branches except master or main example

Tags: git

**Delete all branches except master branch**

1. Your all local branch will be deleted except main or master branch branch
2. This command do not affect the remote server

Comment: Obviously this was already asked and answered extensively years ago... (which is also the first Google hit when searching for your question title)

Answer (score 3):

To delete all branches in your Git repository except master, simply issue the following command:

`$ git branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D`

If you want to delete branches such as master-prod, master-test or master-ui, you can adjust the RegEx used by the grep as follows:

`$ git branch | grep -v " master$" | xargs git branch -D`